# Remove all binary characters from a file

Tags: csv, binary

Occasionally, I have a hard time manipulating data in a CSV file because of the following error.

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

I researched several articles online but cannot seem to find one that helps me remove all of the binary characters or elements from a CSV file.

Unfortunately, I do not know where to start with this.

If I run the 'file' command on the file, I get the following output:

```
Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR line terminators
```

The second from last line in the file prints as:

```
"???? ?????, ???? ???",????,"?????, ????",???,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,* Home,email@address.com,,
```

The second line in the file prints as:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,* ,email@address.com,,
```

This file contains too many lines to open in Excel or a GUI, "Save as..." and remove the binary elements that way.

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: LC_ALL='C' sort -u ~/path/to/file.csv at least got me out of that Binary error. If there is better way, please let me know.

Comment: However, when I did a 'egrep '@' input.csv | tee output.csv', I got 'Binary file input.csv matches'